# Request of Angular dont map my API in BackEnd (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, angular, spring, api, spring-boot

I have a bug, i dont know why, but angular dont active my api in spring boot, and i dont find the error.

This is the code.

**SERVICE (ANGULAR)**

```
setPost(postId:number):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.http.post<boolean>(this.myAppUrl+this.myApiPostUrl+postId+'/setPost',this.authService.getLoggedUserFromSessionStorage())
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      );
  }
```

**COMPONENT (ANGULAR)**

```
isAlreadyOpen(){
    this.postService.isOpen(this.postId).subscribe( isAuth => {
      if(isAuth) {
        this.cantModify();
      } else {
        console.log('im here');
        this.postService.setPost(this.postId);
        this.router.navigate(['/post/edit/', this.postId]);
      }
  });
  }
```

The code enter without problem in else, because chrome console print 'im here'.

**CONTROLLER (JAVA)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts/{id}/setPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> setPost(@PathVariable("id") int idPost, @RequestBody UserDTO userCorrente) {
        PostUser postUser = postUserService.set(idPost, userCorrente);
        if (postUser != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**Angular**
`this.postService.isOpen` (This api, work perfectly)

Dont work `this.postService.setPost`, i tried to remove all to see if map, like that

```
isAlreadyOpen(){
        this.postService.setPost(this.postId);
        this.router.navigate(['/post/edit/', this.postId]);
      }
  }
```

but nothing, dont work, i dont see the request in DEV TOOLS (Network) of Chrome, and i dont see nothing in Spring Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `subscribe()` on `this.postService.setPost(this.postId)`, otherwise the request won't be triggered.

Comment: Thanks so much, i didnt notice. You saved my day.